# Orders module Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module

my Site is working fine but when i open orders from admin panel then it shows error.

i googled and try to fix issue but i failed, i got this problem after configuration of payment method.

If anyone Know , kindly help me [image: when i click on Orders it occurs]

Comment: In which payment method you configureed.

Comment: I use Stripe method